# Printing data in Python

Tags: python

I have the following data stored in a csv file

```
id        x        y     name
312       33.76    55.2   aaa
312       33.76    55.2   aaa
443       66.33    11.5   ccc
686       44.55           ddd
222                44.6   eee
423       88.3     23.6   fff
```

and I had use the following code to find out the popularity 
    popularity = dict(Counter(data['id']))
    print "id\tpopularity"

```
for k, v in popularity.items():
    print '{0:.0f}\t{1}'.format(k,v)
```

and I had find out the unique id using this code

```
 uni_id = np.unique(data['id'])
```

Now I want to print out the unique id with x , y and the popularity but not with name and need to ignore the column without x or y

like this :

```
  id        x        y       popularity
  312       33.76    55.2     2
  443       66.33    11.5     1   
  423       88.3     23.6     1
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the last part you described? Indicate what parts of it are giving you difficulty?

Comment: my question is how to combine this two code and print out the table , i have no idea how to do

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but it wasn't tested:

```
import csv

class Row(object):

    def __init__(self, id, x, y, name):
        self.id = id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name

column_names = [] # here lies first row from csv file
rows = [] # list of Row-class objects
file = None # file we loaded

with open("filename.csv", newline='') as f:
    file = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') # this loads csv file and splits it by
                        # '' as newline and ',' as data seperator
                        # file is now table full of data looking like this:
                        # [[id, x, y, name], [312, 33.76, 55.2, 'aaa'],...]

columns_names = file[:1]  # first row of file are column names
file = file[1:]  # slicing our list
for row in file:
    rows.append(Row(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))  # creating Row-class objects

print(column_names)
for row in rows:
    print(("%s %s %s %s" % (row.id, row.x, row.y, row.name))
```

This code shows you how to load and parse csv file. What you need now is add few `if` statemens in `for` loop to ignore rows withour `x` or `y` data.
Probably you'll need some reading about [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)